# how to fix Error: ASSERTION ERROR: Should be run in update mode [Expected=> false == true <=Actual]

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

Im writing a code with in angular with ChangeDetectorRef

The function itself is working fine.

```
getVersionInfos() {
concat(
  of(
    this.getApiSubs = this.aboutInfoService.getApiVersion().subscribe((data) => {
      if (data) {
        this.apiData = data;
        this.applicationCopyright = data.find(dt => dt.Name === "Web API Details").Value;          }
    })
  ),
  of(
    this.getEngineSubs = this.aboutInfoService.getEngineVersion().subscribe((data) => {
      if (data) {
        this.engineData = data;
        this.engineDetails = data.find(dt => dt.itemcode === "VER").versiontext;
        this.cd.detectChanges();
      }
    })
  )
);
```

}

When i wrote the Unit Test code for it keeps on failing on the

```
        this.cd.detectChanges();
```

which gives me this error

Error: ASSERTION ERROR: Should be run in update mode [Expected=> false == true <=Actual]

and this is the spec code block

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [
    AboutComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    MatBottomSheetModule,
    HttpClientTestingModule
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: AboutInfoService,
      useValue: jasmine.createSpyObj("AboutInfoService", [
        "getApiVersion",
        "getEngineVersion"
      ]),
    },
    {
      provide: ChangeDetectorRef,
      useValue: jasmine.createSpyObj("ChangeDetectorRef", ["detectChanges"])
    }
  ]
})
.compileComponents();

aboutInfoService = TestBed.get(AboutInfoService);
aboutInfoService.getApiVersion.and.returnValue(of(mockApiResponse));
aboutInfoService.getEngineVersion.and.returnValue(of(mockEngineResponse));



}));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AboutComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it("should create", () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
```

if i remove the code

```
        this.cd.detectChanges();
```

from the function it will pass the unit test

Comment: Do you call the `getVersionInfos` function inside the component's constructor?

Comment: thank you, i changed the location of the function and placed it on ngOnInit @shalom

Answer (score 72, accepted):

I got it all working,

I have placed the function getVersionInfos in the ngOnInit instead of inside the constructor

Answer (score 34):

I've this error too in Angular 11. The problem was that I was executing:

```js
this.cdr.detectChanges();
```

Inside the constructor, that is wrong. I moved It to ngOnInit()

Answer (score 18):

Avoid keeping `this._changeDetectorRef.detectChanges()` method call in the constructor or in the method which will get called from the constructor. Angular will throw this error in both cases.

Comment: any explanation why?

Answer (score 1):

I Noticed this issue too, this issue is mostly because of conflict in angular cli version, i had the angular cli version of `11.1.2`, i have downgraded to `11.0.7` and it worked for me.

In my case, this issue was causing the UI to not to load properly.

As i saw other answers, moving the functions or code from `Constructor` to `ngOnInit` is not the good option, it just the matter of cli version compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to include any custom components used in your component.
Just include the child component name in declarations in your .spec.ts (along with an import of course).

Answer (score 0):

If you have a project with module federation, check angular packages version in the host app and connected apps, they must match exactly.
After editing versions, remove node_modules and **package-lock.json** and install them again.