# Material dialog pops up blank before showing letters on it

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I am using angular **9.1.13** with material **9.2.4** in my electron application. I have noticed the following strange behaviour concerning the **Material Dialog** component.

When I try to pop up a simple dialog with only text, **the dialog pops up empty in the first place**, and **after some milliseconds (usually 300-1000) the letters are shown up**. Screenshots shown below:

When i open the dialog

[image]

After some milliseconds

[image]

The implementation of the pop up is the following:

**MyDialogComponent**

```
export class MyDialogComponent {
public infoMessage: string;

constructor(
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) private data: any,
    private dialogRef: MatDialogRef<MyDialogComponent>
) {
    if (data) {
        this.infoMessage = data.message;
    }
}

public static getConfig(): any {
    return {
        width: '500px',
        height: 'auto',
        disableClose: true,
        panelClass: 'dialog-info',
        backdropClass: 'dialog-info-bg'
    };
}
}
```

I am popping up the dialog as shown below:

```
const config = MyDialogComponent.getConfig();
config.data = {message: 'My text that comes later than pop up'};
this._dialogService.open(MyDialogComponent, config);
```

where _dialogService is the **MatDialog**

```
private _dialogService: MatDialog
```

**Html code of MyDialogComponent**

```
<div class="modal modal fade">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="message">{{ infoMessage }}</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn modal-btn close-btn">Close
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have searched on the web about this strange behaviour but have not yet found any satisfying answer on how to deal with this issue, thanks in advance

Comment: Check network tab in dev tools, maybe its loading something.

Comment: Dialog does not make any http call to fetch text neither does load any asset like image etc which could maybe cause this 'lag'..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have an issue with change detection - Electron events and APIs don't trigger change detection in Angular. Try using `ChangeDetectorRef` or `NgZone`:

```
import { OnInit, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

...

export class MyDialogComponent implements OnInit {
public infoMessage: string;

constructor(
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) private data: any,
    private dialogRef: MatDialogRef<MyDialogComponent>,
    private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef
) { }

ngOnInit() {
    if (data) {
        this.infoMessage = data.message;
        this.cdr.detectChanges();
    }
}
```

or

```
import { NgZone } from '@angular/core';

...

export class MyDialogComponent {
public infoMessage: string;

constructor(
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) private data: any,
    private dialogRef: MatDialogRef<MyDialogComponent>,
    private zone: NgZone
) {
    if (data) {
        this.zone.run(() => {
            this.infoMessage = data.message;
        });
    }
}
```

Alternately you can make sure the command to open the dialog is properly picked up by Angular's change detection:

```
this.zone.run(() => {
    const config = MyDialogComponent.getConfig();
    config.data = {message: 'My text that comes later than pop up'};
    this._dialogService.open(MyDialogComponent, config);
});
```

If this resolves your problem, keep in mind for the rest of your app that anything coming from Electron will need the same handling in order to update the UI/rendered HTML.

Comment: Thanks for the response, firstly, according to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65712096/how-to-fix-error-assertion-error-should-be-run-in-update-mode-expected-fals `this.cdr.detectChanges();` should be inside ngOnInit hook, otherwise I get runtime error, secondly, it is really hard to reproduce this behaviour now, so I cannot tell if I have a significant improvement in time of the text rendering in the pop up, what could be a way to test it?

Comment: Ah you're right that `this.cdr.detectChanges();` shouldn't be in the constructor, I'll update the answer accordingly. In terms of the behavior, do you mean this problem doesn't always happen? If so, you'll need to figure out how to reliably trigger the issue before you can confirm it's been fixed. Can you describe (or include code for) the events that lead up to the dialog opening? Is there any communication between Electron and Angular beforehand?

Comment: On second thought, it might be better to wrap the `MatDialog.open()` command inside `NgZone.run()` - looks like the problem is related to the dialog itself since the button text also wasn't appearing. I added that to the answer as well. I can't say more about what the best solution would be without more context, but the main point is to make sure Angular's change detection is picking up code/variable changes that impact the UI.

Comment: Performance generally seems to have been improved concerning the response time of pop up dialog using `this.zone.run(()`, I do not know if this the optimal solution but it seems to be working ok :) thank you

Answer (score 2):

You could try [CdkDialog](https://material.angular.io/cdk/dialog/examples) (since you already passing classes to change visuals) which is less resource demanding (affects rendering speed:

The config should be passed directly in a popup call. Instead of creating an `instance of the popup component` before getting config like you do:

```
const config = MyDialogComponent.getConfig(); // which is very weird
```

->

```
const config = {
    width: '500px',
    height: 'auto',
    disableClose: true,
    panelClass: 'dialog-info',
    backdropClass: 'dialog-info-bg'
};
this._dialogService.open(MyDialogComponent, config);
```

And data could be public without `if` in `constructor`, since you always pass it:

```
@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: {message: string},
```

Template:

```
<h5 class="modal-title" id="message">{{ data.message }}</h5>
```

I've never worked with electron, so it may not be enough. You may be executing microtasks when open call happens. You have relatively old Angular version, so it might be old project too, does it have other examples of using dialog?

To measure overall latency you can use `console.log(window.performance.now())` before calling `open` and the same in `ngOnInit` of the popup.